# How to sort a pandas dataframe column by item type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following column in my Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd. Series(['R1', 'R2', 70, -100, 0, -25, 'R7', 'R8'])
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

I want to sort the column such that the output is:

```
['R1', 'R2', 'R7', 'R8', 70, -100, 0, -25]
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Why don't you just sort the dataframe while creating it? So just use `df =  pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(['R1', 'R2', 'R7', 'R8', 70, -100, 0, -25]))`

Comment: How is 70< -100? why is 0 < -25? What's the sorting logic?

Comment: Please explain your sorting logic

Comment: my sorting logic is to just group it according to the type without changing the sequence.

Comment: I cannot do the sort it while creating because Im not creating it myself, it is derived from other data. Just for the sake of this qestion, I created it here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving this with example to handle the 2 `types` which you have mentioned in your question :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['random_vals'] = pd.Series(['R1', 'R2', 70, -100, 0, -25, 'R7', 'R8'])

def sort_by_type(random_types_list):
  str_list = []
  int_list = []
  for elem in random_types_list:
    if isinstance(elem, str):
      str_list.append(elem)
    elif isinstance(elem, int):
      int_list.append(elem)
  return str_list+int_list

print(sort_by_type(list(df['random_vals'])))
```

Output of the `print` statement :

```
>>> print(sort_by_type(list(df['random_vals'])))
['R1', 'R2', 'R7', 'R8', 70, -100, 0, -25]
```

---

Similarly you can add the code in `sort_by_types` method for other `data-types` aswell.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Sowanja! I liked that approach, but all the other columns of the data frame won't change along with it. Is there any way to shuffle all columns with this column?

Comment: will try that out